# for loop don't work on kivy python

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Hi: im trying to do a simple app on kivy and have an error in a loop.

Explain: i have 10 screens in the ScreenManager and i need clear all widgets except 4 of them.

A button on_press call the update() method of the ScreenManager.

The error: in the update() method i have the following code:

```
   self.static_screens = ['list', 'new', 'conf', 'edit']  # declared in __init__ method

    def update():
        for screen in self.screens:
            if screen.name not in self.static_screens:
                self.remove_widget(screen)
```

the execute normally but remove just one widget (screen) from the ScreenManager

Comment: Are you mutating an object that you are iterating over? If `self.remove_widget(screen)` mutates `self.screens`, then that would be your issue. You need to refactor.

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i fix it?, creating a copy?

Comment: See my answer. In short, creating a temporary list to store the screens you wish to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `kivy`, but I suspect the issue is that you are mutating an object that you are iterating over. Many people have similar issues when trying to do things such as removing particular items in a list using a `for` loop.

Here is a possible refactoring that might fix your issue.

```
def update():
    screens_to_remove = [screen in self.screens if 
                         screen.name not in self.static_screens]
    for screen in screens_to_remove:
        self.remove_widget(screen)
```

(Note that I haven't tested this, as I'm not sure what the rest of the code looks like.)

Comment: No worries at all. If this solved the problem, you should upvote my answer and mark as accepted. :)